# How to create Content Builder Folder in Marketing Cloud when creating a new Business Unit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder, folder, sfmc-business-unit

When I create a new Business Unit and Access Content Builder from it, I cannot find any available folder for Content Builder. Consequently, I cannot upload as well as create new Email as they don't have root location to save. So how can I create Content Builder Folder in Marketing Cloud when creating a new Business Unit?[image]

Comment: Do you have the right permissions in the new Business Units for that? Try also adding some test content to the canvas so you can see if it works well or not. If yes, I would suggest you open a ticket to support.

Comment: I would also try opening it inside a different browser. Sometimes there can be a hiccup that is cached on your computer that makes it so Content Builder does not load all the way. Switching browsers or logging out and clearing cache may also solve it.

Answer (score -2):

Create your own folder structure by right-clicking on Content Builder or a parent folder to create a subfolder [Here is the Link for reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_ceb_folder_management.htm&type=5).

Comment: Looks like you need to complete your answer.
please give more detailed responses.
Not sure who downvoted your answer but if you had given an accurate solution/answer to the above question you may not have been downvoted.